# What does “much to his chagrin” mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does *much to his chagrin* mean?

If *chagrin* means feeling of embarrassment, then can we write “I felt chagrin” or the like? What about “I was chagrined by”?

Then what does *much to chagrin* mean in a sentence, or is this the way we put it?

Comment: “Much to [someone’s] _X_ ” is a set construction denoting that something causes a strong feeling of _X_ in the person named. So “much to my chagrin” means ‘causing me a great deal of chagrin’; “much to my dismay” means ‘causing me a great deal of dismay’, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet suggest you post as answer

Answer (score 6):

**Chagrin** as a **Verb** means:

> Feel annoyed and disappointed

**Chagrin** as a **Noun** mean:

> Annoyance and disappointment because something has not happened the
>   way you hoped

**To sb's Chagrin means** means feeling Displeased or Ashamed because of a situation.

Comment: So is the meaning slighly different when used as "To sb's Chagrin" ? Switching to disappointment to embarassment ?

Comment: yeah, i believe so. Am i wrong?

Comment: I have no idea: we need a native speaker (it would seems a little strange though)

Comment: Your definition of *Chagrin* as a noun is accurate enough, though it would be nice if you could say where you got it from (I suggest you edit in the source). I have never heard the word as a verb. And there is no reason (that I know of) why the meaning would change in a normal construction like *much to his...* So *much to his chagrin, the car broke down* is a simpler way of saying *The car broke down, which disappointed and annoyed him*.

Comment: The verb form is uncommon, but I've seen it, usually as a participle like “I'm chagrined to learn that.”

Comment: @BraddSzonye That’s not a verb form: it’s an adjective like saying *a red-headed person*. There is no verb *∗red-head* there. Similarly with adjectives like *toothed, booted, wooded, moneyed, cultured, diseased, jaundiced,  dark-eyed, seven-hilled, leather-aproned, bigoted, crabbed, dogged*. In other words, this is **not** the *-ed* we add to verbs to make past participles, but rather the *-ed* that we add to nouns to make adjectives “connoting the possession or the presence of the attribute or thing expressed by the noun.” Meanings include “possessing, provided with, characterized by”. [OED]

Comment: Sure thing. The OED says that *chagrin* as a verb is archaic.  It means “To trouble, vex, worry, grieve. *arch.”* One citation given is “Every word they say **chagrins** us, and we know not where to begin to set them right.” from Emerson in the early 1840s. As @BraddSzonye said, I don’t think it gets used much these days. They say it is usually used in the passive, like “Surprised and **chagrined** by the coldness of her manner.” There is also an 18th century citation of an apparent intransitive use: “ I would not have your ladyship **chagrin** at my bride’s expression.” from 1727 in Fielding.

Comment: @tchrist, I have to disagree with your first comment—in this case, the adjective ‘chagrined’ _is_ a participle of the verb in origin, not a nominal derivation. The adjectives derived from nouns and adjectives do not accept agentive complements, which ‘chagrined’ does: “She was much chagrined by the news of his failure”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You’re right, I’m wrong.